# What's the complete rule regarding double bouncing balls inside the popping crease?

Tags: rules, cricket

I've been trying to figure out the possible outcomes in case a ball double bounces off the cricket pitch. I read [Law 20](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-20-dead-ball/) and [Law 21](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-no-ball/). Law 20 does not reference double bounced balls. Law 21 says:

> The umpire shall call and signal No ball if a ball which he/she considers to have been delivered, without having previously touched bat or person of the striker,
>
> - bounces more than once or rolls along the ground *before it reaches the popping crease*

But what if double bounces inside the popping crease? And then possibly stumps the batsman? Is there another rule or law regarding that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's it - if the ball bounces twice *before* it reaches the popping crease, it's a no ball. If it bounces twice on or after the popping crease, it's a fair delivery.

> And then possibly stumps the batsman?

A ball cannot stump a batsman; that can only be accomplished by the wicket-keeper. If you mean the ball hits the wicket and permanently dislodges the bails, then the batsman is out bowled.

Comment: Sir, would [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfW-Mus5b8c) be out?

Comment: No, because the umpire signalled "No ball" :-) That video is from a 1999 match so would have been played under the [1980 code](http://static.espncricinfo.com/db/ABOUT_CRICKET/LAWS/1980_CODE/); in that, [Law 24](http://static.espncricinfo.com/db/ABOUT_CRICKET/LAWS/1980_CODE/LAW_24_NO_BALL.html) makes no mention of no balls for bouncing twice, so this must have been due to the playing conditions for the specific match. Good luck finding those!

Comment: Sir, I wanted to ask as per this new rule would that be out or not.

Comment: I believe it would be out, but I'm not a qualified referee in any way, so don't put any money on it!

Comment: The ball looks to have made the second bounce between crease and stumps. Decision: out. @RamChandraGiri

Comment: "A ball cannot stump a batsman" haha yeah I meant the other meaning. Thanks though :)

Answer (score -3):

If the ball bounces once before it reaches the striker , then it will be No Ball Call And signal , remember it not a dead ball , so If the striker hits the ball and attempts a run or its a boundary  , it will be scored and recorded in the credit of striker , there is no Rule MCC 2019 edition ,  which say that , it will be called dead .... Read Law MCC 21 .7
See it is Amended and the change is  more than once , not more than twice , for now onwards MCC

Comment: The ball bouncing only once before the striker is no reason to call and signal No ball; this is how the vast majority of balls delivered occur, and would make the game a farce.

Comment: This is wrong in all respects.